# How to escape comma and double quote at same time for CSV file?

Tags: java, regex, excel, oracle, csv

I am writing a Java app to export data from Oracle to csv file

Unfortunately the content of data may quite tricky. Still comma is the deliminator, but some data on a row could be like this:

```
| ID    |   FN    |   LN   |  AGE   |  COMMENT                   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 123   |  John   |  Smith |   39   | I said "Hey, I am 5'10"."  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

so this is one of the string on the `comment` column:

> I said "Hey, I am 5'10"."

No kidding, I need to show above comment without compromise in excel or open office from a CSV file generated by Java, and of course cannot mess up other regular escaping situation(i.e. regular double quotes, and regular comma within a tuple). I know regular expression is powerful but how can we achieve the goal with such complicated situation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Oracle (and the rest of the major RDBMSs) has an 'export' function that performs this function.  Barring that, there's probably an open-source version that would interface with pretty much anything through JDBC, given how common this type of functionality is needed.

Comment: Thanks X-Zero but here the job actually relies on the controller side. But still very helpful idea :)

Comment: For Swift, https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV is rfc4180

Answer (score 123, accepted):

There are several libraries. Here are two examples:

---

#### [❐ Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

[Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) includes a special class to escape or unescape strings (CSV, EcmaScript, HTML, Java, Json, XML): [**`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils`**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).

- *Escape* to CSV

  ```
  String escaped = StringEscapeUtils
      .escapeCsv("I said \"Hey, I am 5'10\".\""); // I said "Hey, I am 5'10"."

  System.out.println(escaped); // "I said ""Hey, I am 5'10""."""
  ```
- *Unescape* from CSV

  ```
  String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils
      .unescapeCsv("\"I said \"\"Hey, I am 5'10\"\".\"\"\""); // "I said ""Hey, I am 5'10""."""

  System.out.println(unescaped); // I said "Hey, I am 5'10"."
  ```

<sub>* *You can download it from* [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22commons-lang3%22).</sub>

---

#### [❐ OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

If you use [**OpenCSV**](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), you will not need to worry about escape or unescape, only for write or read the content.

- Writing file:

  ```
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("awesomefile.csv"); 
  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
  CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(osw);
  ...
  String[] row = {
      "123", 
      "John", 
      "Smith", 
      "39", 
      "I said \"Hey, I am 5'10\".\""
  };
  writer.writeNext(row);
  ...
  writer.close();
  osw.close();
  os.close();
  ```
- Reading file:

  ```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("awesomefile.csv"); 
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
  CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr);

  for (String[] row; (row = reader.readNext()) != null;) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
  }

  reader.close();
  isr.close();
  fis.close();
  ```

<sub>* *You can download it from* [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.opencsv%22).</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the advice Paul. It is an good idea and quite flexible with rgx but can we achieve that without additional libraries?

Comment: And once again Paul it is a really supportive idea and useful piece information if in the next project, I can have to privilege to add more dependencies in Maven. :D

Comment: commons lang sucks because of this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-857; It even sucks more because people patched the issue but there is no release date

Comment: **Fixed** since Apache Commons Lang 3.2

Comment: StringEscapeUtils has no escapeCsv method

Comment: @user1406269 Actually, yes. **☺** Are you the *downvoter*? — Are you using the «**correct**» library?

Comment: Paul's link at the start of his answer to Apache Commons Lang leads directly to the page with the maven coordinates for the library and a download link. Its version 3.3.2 (or even later depending on when this comment is read).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Programmers should not re-invent the wheel (unless there's a really good reason).

Comment: @green How can you say that the entire commons lang sucks because a utility method throws an exception when you give it random binary data with invalid UTF-8 code points? I would argue that it's a feature, to protect against injection.

Comment: @JamesWatkins interesting argument, if this is a feature why do they bother fixing it in 3.2 and mark the type as "bug" ? BTW when I say commons sucks, I mean it sucks in this context, i.e. "escape comma and double quote".

Comment: Sorry to ask a question. But I don't see any escape of the comma inside the string. I am having issues where Open Office and Excel thinks it is a separator even though it is in quotes.

Comment: @user1567291 Though not explicitly mentioned in the answer, it works for comma escapes also.

Answer (score 36):

Excel has to be able to handle the exact same situation.

Put those things into Excel, save them as CSV, and examine the file with a text editor.  Then you'll know the rules Excel is applying to these situations.

Make Java produce the same output.

The formats used by Excel are published, by the way...

****Edit 1:**** Here's what Excel does
****Edit 2:**** Note that php's `fputcsv` does the same exact thing as excel if you use " as the enclosure.

```
rdeslonde@mydomain.com
Richard
"This is what I think"
```

gets transformed into this:

```
Email,Fname,Quoted  
rdeslonde@mydomain.com,Richard,"""This is what I think"""
```

Comment: Tony that's a good idea. I should think that way then it should be an easy job.

Comment: How to escape `""""` ?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux by doing this """"""""" This is what I think, suckas! """"""""" :)

Comment: Bad answer. Apache commons does everything without MS Excel.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to both Tony and Paul for the quick feedback, its very helpful. I actually figure out a solution through POJO. Here it is:

```
if (cell_value.indexOf("\"") != -1 || cell_value.indexOf(",") != -1) {
    cell_value = cell_value.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
    row.append("\"");
    row.append(cell_value);
    row.append("\"");
} else {
    row.append(cell_value);
}
```

in short if there is special character like comma or double quote within the string in side the cell, then first escape the double quote(`"\""`) by adding additional double quote (like `"\"\""`), then put the whole thing into a double quote (like `"\""+theWholeThing+"\""` )

Answer (score 5):

You could also look at how [Python writes Excel-compatible `csv` files.](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

I believe the default for Excel is to double-up for literal quote characters - that is, literal quotes `"` are written as `""`.

Comment: Thank you Li-aung. I wasn't get your post before post my own answer. Python does get more library methods for CVS producing.

Comment: Original question doesn't mention Python.

Comment: @JamesWatkins: OP doesn't mention Python - nonetheless, there is useful information in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using CSVWriter. Check that you don't have the option

```
.withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
```

When I removed it the comma was showing as expected and not treating it as new column

Comment: CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER); if you create the csvwrite like this, the comma will not be processed properly.

Comment: @silver_fox Thanks a lot. It saved my time

Answer (score 2):

```
"cell one","cell "" two","cell "" ,three"
```

Save this to csv file and see the results, so double quote is used to escape itself

**Important Note**

```
"cell one","cell "" two", "cell "" ,three"
```

will give you a different result because there is a space after the comma, and that will be treated as "

Answer (score 0):

```
String stringWithQuates = "\""+ "your,comma,separated,string" + "\"";
```

this will retain the comma in CSV file

Comment: Note that the question has already been answered, and the answer has been accepted. Your proposes solution does not escace commas.

Answer (score 0):

In openCSV, use below method to create csvWriter obj,

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
```

In this, `DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER`  is very important.
It will work perfectly, If you want to insert any ',' or '"' in csv file.