# Java: using properties with N values for 1 key

Tags: java, properties

Good morning, i'm making a program for backup.
In the config file i need specify N source directories and theyr destination directories, like this:

```
source="source dir", "destination drive1", "destination drive2"
source="source dir2", "destination drive", "destination drive2"
```

but in properties i can have only one value for a key, so i use different keys for source1, source2 etc.

there is a workaround for this?

ps what is the correct way to split the above string 
"source dir", "destination drive1", "destination drive2"
if i split with " it's easy, but if i have something like

```
"i feel ""good"" because i'm a java programmer", "i feel "very bad" because i'm a java programmer"
```

i can't use string.split("""") because the " in "good" will split the string.

thank you very much

Comment: u can have HashMap<String,List<String>>..

Answer (score 0):

For splitting by `"` symbol :

```
String[] split = s.split("\"");
```

And if you want to have `"` sign in `String` you need to wtite `\"` instead `"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could save it to a JSON file if you want. A full example to save and read in [*JSON.Simple Example – Read And Write JSON*](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/).

In another way, you need escape the double quotes on save. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452463/870248

Answer (score 0):

I see three solutions.

### Many Keys, One Value

```
source1a="source"
source1b="destination one"
source1c="destination two"
source2a="source"
source2b="destination one"
source2c="destination three"
```

### One Key, One Value

```
source1=source,destination one,destination two
source2=source,destination one,destination two
```

For this, use String.split(",") to parse the values.

### XML

Because properties are so 20th century.

```
<configills>
  <blam hoot="source">
    <destination value="destination one"/>
    <destination value="destination two"/>
  </blam>
  <blam hoot="source2">
    <destination value="destination one"/>
    <destination value="destination two"/>
  </blam>
</configills>
```

Comment: If I was doing a simple xml design; SAX seems fine.  For something more complicated check out JAXB.  Also, Spring has great JAXB support (and Castor and JiBX as well as others).