# How to have not get the double quotes doubled with Open CSV?

Tags: java, parsing, csv, opencsv

I write a CSV file with Open CSV (in version 2.3).

In my CSV file I want to write the following line :
I choose a "hero" for this adventure

But I don't find the correct configuration and finally my line is printed, in my CSV file, like that :
I choose a ""hero"" for this adventure

So my code is :

```
CSVWriter writer = null;
writer  = new CSVWriter(outputStreamWriter,';',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

String[] lines = new String[4] ;

lines[0] = "Where is Brian" ;
lines[1] = "42" ;
lines[2] = "I choose a "hero" for this adventure" ;
lines[3] = "May the fourth be with you" ;

for (String line : lines ) {
    writer.writeNext(line );        
}

writer.close();
```

How can I write correctly my line ?

Maybe I must use the CSVParser class ?

Comment: why dont you add escape character

Comment: What does it change ?

Comment: I did suggest the same thing what Jordi & Marcin are saying. putting a " \ "  before open " in  your sentence would tell JVM that it should not be taken as end of string.

Hope you understood.

Comment: I try both solutions but it didn't work. I recreate a String with a StringBuffer but at the end I have the double quotes which are doubled.

Comment: [take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451842/how-to-escape-comma-and-double-quote-at-same-time-for-csv-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to my problem, it's not the best because it's not generic, but it's work in my case. I have to call the following function :

```
public void replaceDoubledQuotesInFile(File file) throws IOException {

    File tempFile = new File("temp.csv");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);

    Reader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while(br.ready()) {

        String readenLine = br.readLine();

        if(readenLine.contains("\"\"")){

            String str1 = readenLine.replaceAll("\"\"", "!");
            String str2 = str1.replaceAll("!", "\"");

            fw.write(str2 + "\n");
            }
        else{
            fw.write(readenLine + "\n");}
    }

    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();

    file.delete();
    tempFile.renameTo(file);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape the quotes

```
lines[2] = "I choose a \"hero\" for this adventure";
```

Or Use single quotes:

```
lines[2] = 'I choose a "hero" for this adventure';
```

Or

```
lines[2] = "I choose a 'hero' for this adventure";
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all, I try the 3 solutions. Maybe there is a problem with the CSVWriter configuration

Comment: did you take a look in the link I commented? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451842/how-to-escape-comma-and-double-quote-at-same-time-for-csv-file maybe can help

Comment: Yes I visited your link but it can't help me. I got a List of String, I search if it contains " and try to replace it by \" but it doesn't work. I also build a string with a StringBuilder (with .append("\"") ). The line writer.writeNext(line ); double the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As documentation says:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

just use:

```
lines[2] = "I choose a \"hero\" for this adventure" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have to escape the input but if you do not want the output escaped you can create the writer with the CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER.  Here is a sample JUnit that shows what I am talking about.

```
@Test
public void embeddedQuoteInString() {
  String[] line = {"Foo", "I choose a \\\"hero\\\" for this adventure"};
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  CSVWriter csvw = new CSVWriter(sw, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER);
  csvw.writeNext(line);
  assertEquals("\"Foo\",\"I choose a \\\"hero\\\" for this adventure\"\n", sw.toString());
}
```