# Writing xml content with comma ',' to csv

Tags: java, csv

My csv file is a comma delimited file. I need to write XML contained in a variable to last cell of each row as part of my requirement. This XML contains `commas(')` which when written through CSVWriter, writes incorrectly. each comma is treated as delimiter and the XML is split into different cells.

Part of my xml as sample

```
<tns:Nature>Residential</tns:Nature>
<tns:Type>Duplex</tns:Type>
<tns:OccupancyPurpose>Owner Occupied Primary Residence</tns:OccupancyPurpose>
<tns:Valuation>
<tns:Sequence>1</tns:Sequence>
<tns:ValuationAmount>700000</tns:ValuationAmount>
<tns:ValuationDate>2014-08-13</tns:ValuationDate>
<tns:ValuerCompany>C J A **Replace_Comma** Lee **Replace_Comma** Property</tns:ValuerCompany>
<tns:ValuationType>Electronic Assessment</tns:ValuationType>
</tns:Valuation>
```

My code goes as below.

```
    strLine = strLine + strXMLContent;
    File file = new File(strFilePath); 

        FileWriter outputfile = null;
        try 
        {
            outputfile = new FileWriter(file,true);
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile,',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,System.getProperty("line.separator"));;

            String arr[] = strLine.split(",",-1);
            for(int i = 0;  i< arr.length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = arr[i].replace("Replace_Comma", ","); //Replaces filler as a comma before being placed in csv
            }
            writer.writeNext(arr);
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The filler when translated as a comma is treated as a delimiter and the following text is written in the next cell.

I have tried many things but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing each data between ' or " ? (That CSVWriter constructor gives me hints it should be possible - CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)

Comment: I tried CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER but it replaces some other quote characters instead of adding to each field

Comment: According to the javadoc that parameter should instruct the Writer to quote all datas with its "quoteChar", what do you mean it replaces other quotes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the help of answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451842/how-to-escape-comma-and-double-quote-at-same-time-for-csv-file) question and using the below,

```
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(strXML);   

File file = new File("File.csv");
String arr[] = 
{
        "123456789&94859614357",
        escaped
};

FileWriter outputfile = null;
try 
{
        outputfile = new FileWriter(file,true);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile,',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,System.getProperty("line.separator"));;
        writer.writeNext(arr);
        writer.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @BigMike suggested,
Replacing

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile,',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,System.getProperty("line.separator"));;
```

with

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile);
```

or

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile,',', CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

should work.

Comment: Sorry to say it did not work. I am facing the same problem

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar can you please share your version of **opencsv** ?

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar can you please also share _content_ of generated **csv** file.

Comment: FYI: mine **opencsv** version was **opencsv-5.0**